# I want to add a string to another string with {} around that string

Tags: python, string-formatting

From the title it sounds very confusing but this is what I'm trying to say.
We have a `word`, and I want to add it to `mystring = ""` but I want to have {} around the `word` (mind you I cant hard code it, I just have to use that variable)

Normally to add a string to another string, I would do:

```
mystring += word
```

But I want to add {} around the word

I've tried doing:

```
mystring += {word}
```

^ {word} is not a string (different types)

```
mystring += "{word}"
```

^ this just outputs {word} when you print it and not what the output string of word is

```
mystring += f"{{word}}"
```

^ this outputs the same thing as above

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

> The parts of the string outside curly braces are treated literally, except that any doubled curly braces '{{' or '}}' are replaced with the corresponding single curly brace.

So you need one pair of curly brackets more:

```
mystring += f'{{{word}}}'
```

Answer (score 6):

Excerpt from [PEP-498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/):

> Note that the correct way to have a literal brace appear in the
> resulting string value is to double the brace:
>
> ```
> >>> f'{{ {4*10} }}'
> '{ 40 }'
> >>> f'{{{4*10}}}'
> '{40}'
> ```

Your double braces therefore become literal braces, and to allow `word` to be evaluated as an expression you should therefore surround it with another pair of braces:

```
mystring += f"{{{word}}}"
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use a differnt type of formatting than using an f-string:

```
my_string += "{%s}" % word
```

Comment: This is a good general approach to keeep in mind when encountering issues with format specifiers - swap formatting scheme.  For example, if you are generating a Django or Jinja template they also use `{}`.  So drop into `%(word)s`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something without any formatting, you can use

```py
mystring += "{" + word + "}"
```